# Cron job execution triggered by drone always delay

Tags: cron, drone.io

I set a cron job with my self hosting drone server. The cron job was always delayed to execute for around 5 minutes. When I switch timezone from UTC to NZST, the delay period expand to around 10 minutes. Using `curl` command to execute the job directly can execute without any delay.

Having some searching, it looks like the delay may related to the hardware for running the server/current network status. But if these are the causes, the delay should not become more severe when I just change the timezone on the server. The delayed period is quite similar (4 ~ 5 minutes before timezone change, 10 ~ 11 minutes after )

I was stuck and don't know what should be the next thing to investigate ... can anyone point me out the possible reason or what should I pay attention to please ? Thanks